# Get object data from openDialog in angular material

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript

Hi i'm new in angular.

So I have this json object:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "2019-A",
    "createdBy": "Adrian",
    "creationDate": "1552211000",
    "orders": [{"id": "1", "name":"2019-01"}, {"id": "2", "name":"2019-02"}]
}
```

This is an object that rappresents an project. So I have a list with projects, when I click one item I show a list with orders of the selected project.

[image]

So I have for each order in the list one button. I would like to show order details when I click the button.

This is the code about button click:

```
<mat-grid-tile>
        <mat-selection-list [multiple]="false">
            <mat-list-option *ngFor="let ord of selectedOrders">
                <span>
                    {{ ord.name }}
                    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="openDialog(ord)">Order Details</button>                    
                </span>                
            </mat-list-option>
        </mat-selection-list>
    </mat-grid-tile>
```

order.component.html:

```
<div>{{id}} - {{name}}</div>
```

projects.component.ts:

```
openDialog(ord: OrderModel) {
    //debugger;
    this.dialog.open(OrdersComponent, {
      data: {
        id: ord.id,
        name: ord.name,
      }
    });
  }
```

This is the result:
[image]

Cannot load id and name of the order. I can see only the - symbol.

Comment: you can do that way `<div>{{data.id}} - {{data.name}}</div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the data on your `OrdersComponent`.

To access the data in your `OrdersComponent`, you have to use the MAT_DIALOG_DATA injection token:

`orders.component.ts`

```js
import {Component, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material/dialog';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-orders-component',
  template: 'passed in {{ data.name }}', // <- note: template calls data
})
export class OrdersComponent {
  constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: {name: string}) { }
}
```

Resources:

https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview

Answer (score 0):

try this

`<div>{{data.id}} - {{data.name}}</div>`

in your example you're injecting data as an object and not id and name individually.

Comment: It's better to include an explanation instead of just the code in your answer.

Comment: @BrunoMonteiro good point, I thought it was self explanatory...but I'll update it

Comment: Stack Overflow will flag your answer if just has the code, that's why :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers